# How to make C enum types available to other languages?

Tags: python, c++, c, fortran

I am currently writing a C/C++ program, which uses a bunch of `enum`s from a header file, say

```
typedef enum
{
    POINT,
    LINE,
    AREA,
    VOLUME
} domainType;
```

My program interfaces with various other languages (F77, F90, Python, ...) and I want these enum types to be once defined in the C/C++ header file and use them also in the other languages. I would like to avoid defining the same "`enum`" types (they might be called differently in other languages...) for every single language I'm interfacing with because this would be a very error-prone task. Is there some elegant way how to do it?

Comment: Assign numbers to them and define them accordingly, and at least for C++ you can use the headers anyway

Comment: What is your interoperation layer with those other languages?

Comment: Code->code conversions are always going to be problematic. Better would be to generate the enums file from a data structure, (xml/yaml/json/etc), and have a script that generates the enums.h/enums.py/etc. for each language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that in all languages you define them as a comma separated list, you might be able to do something like this:

**ENUMS.txt**

```
 POINT,
 LINE,
 AREA,
 VOLUME
```

**Myfile.h**

```
typedef enum
{
#include "ENUMS.txt" 
} domainType;
```

In C/C++ this would work. However I don't know if your other languages have a similar feature like the include in C/C++. If yes, then you can do it in such a way.

I 'm pretty sure that this would not work in Java for example.

Otherwise you can only define them in some config file and map them via functions, but then they wouldn't be enums anymore. If this example is all you have, then it's probablxy not worth the effort, but if you have hundreds of such names, then it might be worth.

**UPDATE**

After thinking about this, there might be some other approach, which would be a bit of work, but might be usefull. For languages which support an include like I showed above, this approach is fine. For other languages, like Java, Python, etc. you could write a simple script which generates a valid sourcefile. I was doing something similar for java to generate database records as classes, based on the definition read from the database.
If you have to support many languages, and/or frequently modify the enums, this might be usefull as you still have a single source to maintain.

Comment: Ok, I was already afraid that there is no straight-forward solution to my problem. It's not hundreds of `enum`s but probably dozens. The nice thing about `enum`s is that they provide an easy way to ensure that only a predefined set of values is allowed to be used; that's why I would like to stick with `enum`s.

Comment: For Fortran 2003 that would work. Just use https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlf101a.doc%2Fxlflr%2Fenum.htm

Comment: I know, but unfortunately, the main focus is on older versions of Fortran (e.g., Fortran 77, Fortran 90).

Comment: I updated with an additional approach I used for a similar problem. Might be an idea for you as well.

Comment: Yeah, I think this is actually the most versatile way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Taking Devolus approach for Python, you can create a dictionary for the enum literals like this:

```
with open('ENUMS.txt', 'r') as f:
    content = f.read().splitlines()      

domainType = {}
index = 1
for enum_literal in content:
    enum_literal = enum_literal.strip() # remove any whitespace
    enum_literal = enum_literal.rstrip(',') # remove comma
    print 'Adding ' + enum_literal + ' to dict'
    domainType [enum_literal] = index
    index = index + 1
```

Then you can use 'domainType' to access your enums.

That'd be one way.  I'm sure there's a million more since this IS Python...